# ASP.net Vb.Net Label.Text not updating

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, label

In my VB.net ASP application, i have some ASPTREEVIEW where, on page load there is a Label, to which i set some value. After clicking on any row, i catch that value & assign it to the label.

But suddenly that label value is not updating by the chosen value. As if i check it via debugging the value, the value changes, but when i use Lable.text = chosen_value... It sets the value, but it is not actually changing on the html page. HTML shows the old value.

What will be the problem, i am not getting it.

```
Imports DevExpress
Imports DevExpress.Xpo
Imports DevExpress.Data
Imports DevExpress.Data.Filtering
Imports System.Data

Partial Class _Default
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

    Public testvar As Integer = 35

    Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
        Dim xpcol As New XPCollection(Of WCSOEE.WcsGCObject)
        Dim GCObj1 As WCSOEE.WcsGCObject
        Dim Filter1 As New DevExpress.XtraCharts.DataFilter
        Dim SelectedGCObject As WCSOEE.WcsGCObject
        Filter1.ColumnName = "Oid"
        Filter1.Condition = XtraCharts.DataFilterCondition.Equal

        Filter1.Value = Label2.Text
        If Label2.Text = "" Then
            Label2.Text = 10
        End If
        For Each Siris As DevExpress.XtraCharts.Series In WebChartControl1.Series
            '  WebChartControl1.Series(Siris.Name).DataFilters.Item(0).Value = CInt(Label2.Text)
        Next


        Dim masterKeyvalue As DevExpress.Web.ASPxTreeList.TreeListNode = ASPxTreeList1.FocusedNode
        If masterKeyvalue IsNot Nothing Then
            SelectedGCObject = masterKeyvalue.DataItem
        Else
            SelectedGCObject = xpcol.Object(31)
        End If

        ' MsgBox(SelectedGCObject.GCName)
        MsgBox(Label2.Text)

        If IsPostBack = False Then
            Label2.Text = calculatehours(SelectedGCObject.Oid)
        End If

    End Sub

    Protected Function calculatehours(Oid As Integer)
        xpocolLogAvailability.Session = DevExpress.Xpo.XpoDefault.Session
        Dim logavail As New XPCollection(Of WCSOEE.LogAvailability)
        Dim gcobjlist As New XPCollection(Of WCSOEE.WcsGCObject)
        gcobjlist.Filter = CriteriaOperator.Parse("[Oid]=?", Oid)
        Dim filter As CriteriaOperator
        Dim ds As New DataTable
        Dim Series As New DevExpress.XtraCharts.Series
        Dim Filter1 As New DevExpress.XtraCharts.DataFilter
        ' Label2.Text = Oid


        logavail.Filter = CriteriaOperator.Parse("GCObject.Oid=?", Oid)
        Filter1.ColumnName = "Oid"
        Filter1.Condition = XtraCharts.DataFilterCondition.Equal
        Filter1.Value = Oid
        Dim arr1(32) As Long
        'For i As Int16 = 1 To 32
        '    arr1(i) = 0
        'Next
        'For Each gcobj As WCSOEE.LogAvailability In logavail
        '    arr1(gcobj.Status) = arr1(gcobj.Status) + gcobj.Duration
        'Next= ""
        'ds.Columns.Add(New DataColumn("Name", System.Type.GetType("System.Int32")))



        For Each Siris As DevExpress.XtraCharts.Series In WebChartControl1.Series

            WebChartControl1.Series(Siris.Name).DataFilters.Item(0).Value = Oid

        Next
        WebChartControl1.RefreshData()

        'For i As Int16 = 1 To 32
        '    ds.Rows.Add(i, arr1(i))
        'Next

        'ASPxListBox1.DataSource = ds
        'ASPxListBox1.DataBind()
        Return Oid
    End Function

    Protected Sub ASPxTreeList1_CustomCallback(sender As Object, e As DevExpress.Web.ASPxTreeList.TreeListCustomCallbackEventArgs) Handles ASPxTreeList1.CustomCallback

    End Sub

    Protected Sub ASPxTreeList1_FocusedNodeChanged(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles ASPxTreeList1.FocusedNodeChanged
        Dim masterKeyvalue As DevExpress.Web.ASPxTreeList.TreeListNode = ASPxTreeList1.FocusedNode
        Dim SelectedGCObject As WCSOEE.WcsGCObject = masterKeyvalue.DataItem
        ' MsgBox(SelectedGCObject.GCName)

        If IsPostBack Then
            Label2.Text = calculatehours(SelectedGCObject.Oid)

        End If

        MsgBox(IsPostBack)
        MsgBox(Label2.Text)


    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: post some code, will be easier to spot!

Comment: Does the code include all the places you are referencing Label2? Anything special in your Label2 markup or javascript or if you are using AJAX UpdatePanel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Post some code so we can see exactly what your doing, without seeing anything so far ensure you have an If statement in your page load to only apply the label text if the current request is not a postback other wise the the label will be set to this on every request.

```
If Not IsPostBack() Then
   lblSomeLabel.Text = "Page load text"
End If
```

Comment: Can you just post what's inside the Page_Load event?

Comment: So thing is, When i Debug the Lable2.Text line it gives the changed value, But on the HTML page it doesn't show the updated value.